# The data from the API appears sequentially as it loads

Tags: swift, rest, fetch-api

I am fetching data from RapidAPI. Since the id number of the data I want to retrieve needs to be specified in the Required Parameters section, I cannot fetch all the data at once. That's why I created an object named `idsToFetch`. The data is coming in, but in the simulator, all the data seems to load quickly one after the other into the labels. I want only the information related to the clicked id to be displayed.

Here is my code:

```
    import UIKit
    import Alamofire
    
    class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
        
        @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var portionLabel: UILabel!
       
        var foodResultData : WelcomeElement?
        let urlData = "https://the-vegan-recipes-db.p.rapidapi.com/"
        var detailedFoods : Welcome?
        let idsToFetch = Array(1...384).map { String($0) }
        var currentIDIndex = 0

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            fetchData()
        }
        func fetchData() {
            let apiKey = ""
            guard currentIDIndex < idsToFetch.count else {
                return
            }
            
            let currentID = idsToFetch[currentIDIndex]
            let url = "\(urlData)\(currentID)"

                AF.request(url, method: .get, headers: ["x-rapidapi-key": apiKey] ).responseData { (response) in

                    switch response.result {
                    case .success(let value):
                        debugPrint(value)
                        
                        if let data = response.data {
                            print(response)
                            do {
                                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                                let foodInfo = try decoder.decode(Welcome.self, from: data)
                                
                                self.detailedFoods = foodInfo
                                
                                if let foodInfo = self.detailedFoods {
                                    
                                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                        self.timeLabel.text = foodInfo.time
                                        self.portionLabel.text = foodInfo.portion          
                                    }
                                }
                                print(foodInfo)
                            } catch {
                                print("An error occurred while processing JSON data.: \(error)")
                            }
                        }
                        self.currentIDIndex += 1
                        self.fetchData()
                        
                    case .failure(let error):
                        debugPrint("error:\(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        let navStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) 
        let foodDetailViewController = navStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") as! DetailViewController 
        
        if let currentFood = self.foods?[indexPath.row]
        { 
            foodDetailViewController.foodResultData  = currentFood
        }   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(foodDetailViewController, animated: true)
       }
```

Comment: You are calling `self.fetchData()` recursively from within the API request completion block. If you don't want to keep fetching data after each request finishes, remove this line.

Comment: When I do that, only the data from the first id is displayed every time any cell is clicked.

Comment: There are dedicated patterns for this job: DispatchGroup, TaskGroup and even AsyncSequence.

Comment: I tried to do it using DispatchGroup, but I still only receive data for the first ID. I edited the post. Am I making any mistakes?

Comment: Update after your edit: No, `DispatchGroup` is for loops like `for id in idsToFetch`. And add `group.notify` API to get informed when the transfer is complete.

Comment: In the console, it printed 'All data has been loaded..', but the issue still persists.

Comment: The code overwrites the `text` properties of the labels in each iteration. If you want to load only **one** data record forget the loop and `DispatchGroup` and specify the URL `let url = "\(urlData)\(currentIDIndex)"` if `currentIDIndex` represents the *clicked id*.

Comment: I did it like this `let currentID = idsToFetch[currentIDIndex]` `let url = "\(urlData)\(currentID)"`. Now only one set of data is coming and it's only for the first ID. That means when you click on cells for other IDs, it still shows the data for the first ID.

Comment: You have to call `fetchData` always when the current ID changes. The code for *when you click on cells* is missing.

Comment: I added the `didSelectItemAt` function in the other view controller. I called the `fetchData()` function after changing the current ID, but when I click on a cell in the simulator, all the data for all IDs is being loaded one after another.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out. The code doesn't compile because there is no `foodResultData` in `DetailViewController` and it's unclear what you want to load. It seems that `self.foods?[indexPath.row]` is the item you are looking for. And why is the data source array `foods` optional??

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include the `var foodResultData: WelcomeElement?` in my previous post. I made `foods` optional because I'm getting this error: "Initializer for conditional binding must have an Optional type, not 'WelcomeElement'."